Unable to Retrieve Information from a 'Set' Element within an XML File Using PowerShell
I am trying to retrieve the value from the name="KeyStorePath" attribute, which is within a 'Set' element. See below:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ============================================================= --><!-- SSL ContextFactory configuration                              --><!-- ============================================================= --><!--
  To configure Includes / Excludes for Cipher Suites or Protocols see tweak-ssl.xml example at
     https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory-cipherSuites
--><!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Server" id="sslContextFactory">
  <!-- Eliminate Old / Insecure / Anonymous Ciphers -->
  <Call name="addExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="String">
        <Item>.*NULL.*</Item>
        <Item>.*RC4.*</Item>
        <Item>.*MD5.*</Item>
        <Item>.*DES.*</Item>
        <Item>.*DSS.*</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  <!-- Eliminate Insecure Protocols -->
  <Call name="addExcludeProtocols">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>SSL</Item>
        <Item>SSLv2</Item>
        <Item>SSLv2Hello</Item>
        <Item>SSLv3</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  <Set name="KeyStorePath">D:\VALUE\ADM\VALUE.keystore</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword">REMOVED</Set>
</Configure>

Here is the snippet in my PowerShell script where I'm trying to pull that the needed information:
[xml]$jetty = gc "$CADPathFull\bin\conf\jetty\jetty-ssl-context.xml"
$jettyPath = $jetty.Configure.Set | Where-Object Name -EQ 'KeyStorePath'

If I try to see the value of $jettyPath, it comes up blank/empty. If I try to see the value of $jetty.Configure.Set, I see this information:
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Set(int , System.Object )

Is there something wrong with the structuring of the XML file or am I approaching this incorrectly?
On a side note, I am able to retrieve the Call elements without an issue using $jetty.Configure.Call

Looks like 'set' is also a method in an XmlElement or Array object. A method name without the parentheses shows you the definitions. Even quoting set didn't help. I'm not sure of another workaround. Also put #text in quotes so it's not taken as a comment. You can abbreviate foreach-object as % and where-object as ?.
[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml
$xml.configure | foreach-object set | where-object Name -EQ KeyStorePath | 
  foreach-object '#text'

D:\VALUE\ADM\VALUE.keystore

$xml.configure.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


$xml.configure | get-member set                                                                  

   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement

Name MemberType Definition
---- ---------- ----------
Set  Property   System.Object[] Set {get;}


$xml.configure[0] -eq '' # ???

True


select-xml '/Configure/Set[@name="KeyStorePath"]' file.xml | % node

name         #text
----         -----
KeyStorePath D:\VALUE\ADM\VALUE.keystore


+1 for the effective workaround, but note: While .Set is a CLR-provided member (method) on arrays, XmlElement has no such (type-native) member - you're
merely seeing the adapted properties PowerShell provides for the  <Set> child elements.
It is the  <!DOCTYPE> definition with the same name as the document element, Configure that makes $xml.configure return an array, which causes the problem.

That $xml.configure[0] -eq '' yields $true smells like a bug: as adapted property values, <!DOCTYPE> nodes unexpectedly become the empty string, which has been reported
in  GitHub issue #24721

To locate the <Set /> node with the attribute name set to a value of KeyStorePath, use the following XPath expression:
$keyStorePathSet = $jetty.SelectSingleNode("//Set[@name = 'KeyStorePath']")
$keyStorePathSet.InnerText   # "D:\VALUE\ADM\VALUE.keystore"


Just to provide some framing for future readers: This is an alternative, XPath-based solution that bypasses the OP's problem with PowerShell's property-based XML DOM adaptation.


tl;dr:

You're seeing an edge case of PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM (details in the next section).

The simplest workaround is to use the abstract, type-native .DocumentElement property rather than the document-specific, adapted .Configure property in order to ensure that truly only the XML document (root) element alone is being referenced; in short:
replace $jetty.Configure.Set with $jetty.DocumentElement.Set:
# Note the use of $jetty.DocumentElement in lieu of $jetty.Configure
[xml]$jetty = Get-Content -Raw $CADPathFull\bin\conf\jetty\jetty-ssl-context.xml
$jettyPath = $jetty.DocumentElement.Set | Where-Object Name -EQ KeyStorePath



As an aside:
[xml] (Get-Content ...) should be avoided, because Get-Content may misinterpret the character encoding of XML files. Use the [xml] type's .Load() method instead; e.g.: ($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path ./file.xml)) - see the bottom section of this answer for details.

Background information and detailed explanation:
Fundamentally, your approach relies on PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM:

In essence, PowerShell allows you to treat any [xml] document as an object graph that you can drill into using regular dot notation, because PowerShell surfaces XML child nodes as well as element attributes as namespace-less properties on each object representing an XML element in the graph.

See this answer for details.


When accessing a property on an adapted property (e.g. .Configure.Set) and that adapted property represents multiple child nodes, a standard, type-agnostic PowerShell feature comes into play as well: member-access enumeration:

Accessing a .NET type member (property or method) on an array (list-like collection) implicitly accesses that member on its elements, one by one, and returns the results as an array (except if there's only one result, which is returned as-is); e.g., @((Get-Date 1776/1/1), (Get-Date 2030/1/1)).Year returns @(1776, 2023).

However, if a member by a given name exists on the array / list itself, it takes precedence, and no member-access enumeration is performed; e.g. @('abc', 'abcd').Length yields 2, i.e. the count of elements of the array itself rather than the array of .Length property values of the array elements (i.e., the string lengths, @(3, 4)).


See this answer for details.



In your specific case:

$jetty.Configure.Set doesn't work as intended, because - perhaps surprisingly - two XmlNode children named Configure are reported via the adapted .Configure property at the root of the document, which therefore makes the type of the .Configure property an array ([object[]]):

As expected, the <Configure> document element (an XmlElement instance) is part of that array.

Somewhat obscurely, however, the <!DOCTYPE Configure ...> node (which is of type XmlDocumentType is included too (as the first element of the result array, due to coming first in the XML document), given that that node's name (.Name property value) is 'Configure' too.

As an aside: While surfacing XmlDocumentType nodes as properties too is defensible - in line with surfacing all node types that derive from XmlNode - such a node is currently (as of PowerShell 7.5.0) uselessly represented as an empty string, which has been reported in GitHub issue #24721.




Because an array is returned by $jetty.Configure and because the [Array] type has an - undocumented - Set member, the latter was reported, and because it is a method member, access without () resulted in printing the method's signature.

You can easily recreate this with @().Set
The reason this method isn't documented is that it isn't actually a native member of the [Array] type, but one that is added by the runtime (CLR) - see this post for details.


A workaround therefore requires accessing the document element (<Configure>) alone in order to be able to use its adapted .Set property to get the <Set> child elements (since XmlElement instances have no type-native member called Set, this then succeeds).

The simplest approach is to use the abstract, type-native .DocumentElement property, as shown at the top.

An alternative is to extract the last element ([-1]) from the array that $jetty.Configure returns, which is the document element:
$jetty.Configure[-1].Set | ...





As an aside: Member-access enumeration alternatives, needed when a type-native array / list member takes precedence over the element properties of interest:
Using the @('abc', 'abcd').Length example from above, under the assumption that the .Length property values of the strings that make up the elements of the array are sought.
As noted, the array's .Length property takes precedence, so that 2 (the count of array elements) is returned, requiring a workaround:

The most straightforward, albeit slow solution (which won't matter with small arrays), using the pipeline and ForEach-Object:
# Let the PowerShell pipeline auto-enumerate the array, and use
# ForEach-Object to extract each enumerated element's .Length property value.
# -> @(3, 4)
$stringLengths =
  @('abc', 'abcd') | ForEach-Object Length


The fastest solution requires use of the foreach statement (as opposed to the ForEach-Object cmdlet):
# Use a `foreach` *statement* as an expression.
# -> @(3, 4)
$stringLengths =
  foreach ($el in @('abc', 'abcd')) { $el.Length }


A slightly slower solution than the foreach solution, but faster than the ForEach-Object solution is to use the intrinsic .ForEach() method:
# -> the equivalent of @(3, 4) 
$stringLengths =
  @('abc', 'abcd').ForEach('Length')


Note:

What .ForEach() returns is an array-like data type, namely [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]], and - unlike the other solutions - it does so even if only a single object is returned, i.e. it wraps even a single result in this array-like data type.
That said, in most cases you can simply treat this type as if it were an array (use indexing as you normally would, but use .Count rather than .Length to query the element count (which is also preferable for use with true arrays)); if you truly need an array, you can apply @(...), at the expense of performance.

The above uses the .ForEach() overload that specifies the target member (property) by name as a string; the - slower, but more flexible - alternative is to use a script block ({ ... }):
 # Use a script block ({ ... }), inside of which you can use
 # the automatic $_ variable to refer to the input object at hand.
 $stringLengths =
   @('abc', 'abcd').ForEach({ $_.Length })


Unfortunately, due to a bug (as of PowerShell 7.5.0, if you wanted to use .ForEach() on XML elements, specifically, only the script block-based approach works as intended; see GitHub issue #24721.






